# App ‘plugins’ extending the functionality of a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, plugins

In order to keep initial apk size small what strategies could I use to allow users to extend the functionality of a mobile app by adding optional functionality. Eg I create a social app because that’s what we need ;) and I want user to be able to choose to add a gaming section, or a photo editor section or a chat section, or a paid camera function etc. I don’t want them to have a huge initial download and some people may only want some functionality others may want all. Assuming I have a better reason for putting users through such a thing, does anyone have ideas of how I could make this work?

Comment: Such an approach is prohibited in iOS apps; all functionality must be included in the code that is reviewed by Apple. I wouldn't expect compiled code to be of significant size anyway. Don't try and solve problems before you know they exist

Comment: Thanks Paul that's what I thought I was hoping for some thinking beyond my own angle. Also the problem currently exists but I appreciate your intent.